# Merge Word documents into one and then export to PDF

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, ms-word, office-interop

I am merging Word documents into one using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word with the idea of exporting it to PDF in the end. I need an exact collection of the single documents in one file, but the merging applies unwanted changes. Each single document has it's own page counter (document1: 1/3, 2/3, 3/3; document2: 1/2, 2/2) and I would like this to be the same for the merged document. Unfortunately it becomes 1/5, 2/5... Is there a way to freeze all this dynamically controlled data in the document for the merging? I guess I have to convert the single Word documents to PDF and merge them afterwards (which I tried to avoid)

Comment: An alternative would be create the PDF from the individual documents, and then merge them together. This would definitely retain the page numbering displayed on the pages.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this because of speed issues. Now I have to convert 50 word files to PDF, save them temporary and merge them to one... but I guess that's the only way out

Comment: Follow the other advice, and only if that does not get it right, use this fall-back procedure. You might try to dump a dozen or so Word files onto Acrobat; I think it does support drag and drop in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Building on your discussion with Micky...

Instead of NumPages for the total number of pages use SectionPages, for the total number of pages in a section. You can loop all the Sections' Footer Ranges, and the fields within those Ranges, changing the Field.Code property of the NumPages fields to SectionPages.

Alternately, you can LOCK the Page and NumPages fields in the individual documents before importing so they remain static.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to insert new Word *Section Breaks* between the inserted documents.  Then each section could have a new "start at page number".

Different Page Numbering styles and values can only be applied at the section level I believe.

Comment: I already had added a section break in order to control a header issue. as the first documents header was automatically taken for the second document. But the section break didn't had an impact on the page numbering.

Comment: @Barnabeck You'll still need to tell word to restart the numbering _per_ section